# Bug in timer when trying to post an answer

Tags: bug, answers, rate-limiting

I clicked on "Post your answer" and got a notice saying I can do this only once every 60 seconds.  I had *not* done it in the preceding 60 seconds.  A bug.

Comment: This might be a problem caused by clock differences between a server and your computer. I am not sure how the timing is done for the answer posting timer, but there have been others mentioning problems that sound similar. Even so, this is still a bug because these timings should reference the same clock.

Comment: @MichaelHardy How long did you spend editing your answer before clicking the button?  Can you reproduce this behavior?